# WooCommerce plugin, how to charge 1 giftbasket for multiple products

Tags: checkbox, plugins, woocommerce

I have a problem with my WooCommerce site.

What I currently have is a plugin which allows me to place one checkbox for each product-page, showing "Add this product to a giftbasket?".
The basket will cost 5€ .

The problem is that if the customer wishes to add another product in that same basket, they must click on that page "Add this product to a giftbasket?" checkbox.
This will add another 5€ .
This is what goes wrong.

The goal is to keep it on the price of 1 basket, but at the same time 
giving people the option to add more products without charging another basket for every product, only one time will be needed.

The plugin I'm using has not been updated in 2 years, so asking there is pretty much a dead end.

The plugin I'm using is "WooCommerce Product Gift Wrap".
Link: [here](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-gift-wrap/)

The coding is:

```
<?php
```

/*
Plugin Name: WooCommerce Product Gift Wrap
Plugin URI: 
Description: Add an option to your products to enable gift wrapping. Optionally charge a fee.
Version: 1.1.0
Author: Mike Jolley
Author URI: 
Requires at least: 3.5
Tested up to: 4.0
Text Domain: woocommerce-product-gift-wrap
Domain Path: /languages/

```
Copyright: © 2014 Mike Jolley.
License: GNU General Public License v3.0
License URI:
```

*/

/**
 * Localisation
 */
load_plugin_textdomain( 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap', false, dirname( plugin_basename( **FILE** ) ) . '/languages/' );

/**
 * WC_Product_Gift_wrap class.
 */
class WC_Product_Gift_Wrap {

```
/**
 * Hook us in :)
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct() {
    $default_message                 = '{checkbox} '. sprintf( __( 'Gift wrap this item for %s?', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ), '{price}' );
    $this->gift_wrap_enabled         = get_option( 'product_gift_wrap_enabled' ) == 'yes' ? true : false;
    $this->gift_wrap_cost            = get_option( 'product_gift_wrap_cost', 0 );
    $this->product_gift_wrap_message = get_option( 'product_gift_wrap_message' );

    if ( ! $this->product_gift_wrap_message ) {
        $this->product_gift_wrap_message = $default_message;
    }

    add_option( 'product_gift_wrap_enabled', 'no' );
    add_option( 'product_gift_wrap_cost', '0' );
    add_option( 'product_gift_wrap_message', $default_message );

    // Init settings
    $this->settings = array(
        array(
            'name'      => __( 'Gift Wrapping Enabled by Default?', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
            'desc'      => __( 'Enable this to allow gift wrapping for products by default.', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
            'id'        => 'product_gift_wrap_enabled',
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
        ),
        array(
            'name'      => __( 'Default Gift Wrap Cost', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
            'desc'      => __( 'The cost of gift wrap unless overridden per-product.', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
            'id'        => 'product_gift_wrap_cost',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'desc_tip'  => true
        ),
        array(
            'name'      => __( 'Gift Wrap Message', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
            'id'        => 'product_gift_wrap_message',
            'desc'      => __( 'Note: <code>{checkbox}</code> will be replaced with a checkbox and <code>{price}</code> will be replaced with the gift wrap cost.', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
            'type'      => 'text',
            'desc_tip'  => __( 'The checkbox and label shown to the user on the frontend.', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' )
        ),
    );

    // Display on the front end
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', array( $this, 'gift_option_html' ), 10 );

    // Filters for cart actions
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', array( $this, 'add_cart_item_data' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', array( $this, 'get_cart_item_from_session' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', array( $this, 'get_item_data' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', array( $this, 'add_cart_item' ), 10, 1 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', array( $this, 'add_order_item_meta' ), 10, 2 );

    // Write Panels
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', array( $this, 'write_panel' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', array( $this, 'write_panel_save' ) );

    // Admin
    add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_general_options_end', array( $this, 'admin_settings' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_general', array( $this, 'save_admin_settings' ) );
}

/**
 * Show the Gift Checkbox on the frontend
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
public function gift_option_html() {
    global $post;

    $is_wrappable = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_is_gift_wrappable', true );

    if ( $is_wrappable == '' && $this->gift_wrap_enabled ) {
        $is_wrappable = 'yes';
    }

    if ( $is_wrappable == 'yes' ) {

        $current_value = ! empty( $_REQUEST['gift_wrap'] ) ? 1 : 0;

        $cost = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_gift_wrap_cost', true );

        if ( $cost == '' ) {
            $cost = $this->gift_wrap_cost;
        }

        $price_text = $cost > 0 ? woocommerce_price( $cost ) : __( 'free', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' );
        $checkbox   = '<input type="checkbox" name="gift_wrap" value="yes" ' . checked( $current_value, 1, false ) . ' />';

        woocommerce_get_template( 'gift-wrap.php', array(
            'product_gift_wrap_message' => $this->product_gift_wrap_message,
            'checkbox'                  => $checkbox,
            'price_text'                => $price_text
        ), 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap', untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '/templates/' );
    }
}

/**
 * When added to cart, save any gift data
 *
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $cart_item_meta
 * @param mixed $product_id
 * @return void
 */
public function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_meta, $product_id ) {
    $is_wrappable = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_is_gift_wrappable', true );

    if ( $is_wrappable == '' && $this->gift_wrap_enabled ) {
        $is_wrappable = 'yes';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['gift_wrap'] ) && $is_wrappable == 'yes' ) {
        $cart_item_meta['gift_wrap'] = true;
    }

    return $cart_item_meta;
}

/**
 * Get the gift data from the session on page load
 *
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $cart_item
 * @param mixed $values
 * @return void
 */
public function get_cart_item_from_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

    if ( ! empty( $values['gift_wrap'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['gift_wrap'] = true;

        $cost = get_post_meta( $cart_item['data']->id, '_gift_wrap_cost', true );

        if ( $cost == '' ) {
            $cost = $this->gift_wrap_cost;
        }

        $cart_item['data']->adjust_price( $cost );
    }

    return $cart_item;
}

/**
 * Display gift data if present in the cart
 *
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $other_data
 * @param mixed $cart_item
 * @return void
 */
public function get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( ! empty( $cart_item['gift_wrap'] ) )
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name'    => __( 'In geschenkmand', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
            'value'   => __( 'Yes', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
            'display' => __( 'Ja', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' )
        );

    return $item_data;
}

/**
 * Adjust price after adding to cart
 *
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $cart_item
 * @return void
 */
public function add_cart_item( $cart_item ) {
    if ( ! empty( $cart_item['gift_wrap'] ) ) {

        $cost = get_post_meta( $cart_item['data']->id, '_gift_wrap_cost', true );

        if ( $cost == '' ) {
            $cost = $this->gift_wrap_cost;
        }

        $cart_item['data']->adjust_price( $cost );
    }

    return $cart_item;
}

/**
 * After ordering, add the data to the order line items.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $item_id
 * @param mixed $values
 * @return void
 */
public function add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $cart_item ) {
    if ( ! empty( $cart_item['gift_wrap'] ) ) {
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, __( 'In geschenkmand', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ), __( 'Ja', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ) );
    }
}

/**
 * write_panel function.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
public function write_panel() {
    global $post;

    echo '</div><div class="options_group show_if_simple show_if_variable">';

    $is_wrappable = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_is_gift_wrappable', true );

    if ( $is_wrappable == '' && $this->gift_wrap_enabled ) {
        $is_wrappable = 'yes';
    }

    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array(
            'id'            => '_is_gift_wrappable',
            'wrapper_class' => '',
            'value'         => $is_wrappable,
            'label'         => __( 'Gift Wrappable', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
            'description'   => __( 'Enable this option if the customer can choose gift wrapping.', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
        ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id'          => '_gift_wrap_cost',
            'label'       => __( 'Gift Wrap Cost', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
            'placeholder' => $this->gift_wrap_cost,
            'desc_tip'    => true,
            'description' => __( 'Override the default cost by inputting a cost here.', 'woocommerce-product-gift-wrap' ),
        ) );

    wc_enqueue_js( "
        jQuery('input#_is_gift_wrappable').change(function(){

            jQuery('._gift_wrap_cost_field').hide();

            if ( jQuery('#_is_gift_wrappable').is(':checked') ) {
                jQuery('._gift_wrap_cost_field').show();
            }

        }).change();
    " );
}

/**
 * write_panel_save function.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $post_id
 * @return void
 */
public function write_panel_save( $post_id ) {
    $_is_gift_wrappable = ! empty( $_POST['_is_gift_wrappable'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    $_gift_wrap_cost   = ! empty( $_POST['_gift_wrap_cost'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_POST['_gift_wrap_cost'] ) : '';

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_is_gift_wrappable', $_is_gift_wrappable );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_gift_wrap_cost', $_gift_wrap_cost );
}

/**
 * admin_settings function.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
public function admin_settings() {
    woocommerce_admin_fields( $this->settings );
}

/**
 * save_admin_settings function.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
public function save_admin_settings() {
    woocommerce_update_options( $this->settings );
}
```

}

new WC_Product_Gift_Wrap();

If someone could help me out, then I would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance,

Lynn